# copy system file without shell cp command

Tags: android, shell, root, cp

I need to read a 3rd party db file, so far i copyed the file to the sd card using shell su cp to copy the file to the sd card and read it from there using SQLiteDatabase

but on android 4.1.2 I get a message saying the cp command is missing, /system/bin dont have the file.

how can i read the 3rd patry application db?

I dont want to use busy box, it will drive many users away

I have those commands:
adb, am, app_process, applypatch, atrace, bcm4334.hcd, bcm4334_murata.hcd, bcm4334_semco.hcd, bcm_dut, bintvoutservice, bluetoothd, bmgr, bootanimation, brcm_patchram_plus, brcm_poke_helper, bu, bugreport, cat, chmod, chown, cmp, connfwexe, content, dalvikvm, date, dbus-daemon, dd, ddexe, ddexe_real, debuggerd, dexopt, df, dhcpcd, dmesg, dnsmasq, drmserver, dttexe, dumpstate, dumpsys, e2fsck, fsck.exfat, fsck_msdos, gbias, getevent, getprop, gps.cer, gpsd, gzip, hciattach, hd, hostapd, icd, id, ifconfig, iftop, ime, immvibed, input, insmod, installd, insthk, ioctl, ionice, ip, ip6tables, iptables, keystore, kiesexe, kill, linker, ln, log, logcat, logwrapper, lpmkey, ls, lsmod, lsof, macloader, make_ext4fs, mcDriverDaemon, md5, mdnsd, mediaserver, mfgloader, mkdir, mkfs.exfat, mksh, monkey, mount, mtpd, mv, nandread, ndc, netcfg, netd, netstat, newfs_msdos, notify, npsmobex, p2p_supplicant, pand, ping, playback, playlpm, pm, pppd, printenv, ps, racoon, reboot, renice, requestsync, rild, rm, rmdir, rmmod, route, run-as, samsungani, samsungpowersoundplay, schedtest, schedtop, scranton_RD, screencap, screenshot, sdcard, sdptool, sendevent, sensorservice, service, servicemanager, setconsole, setprop, setup_fs, sh, sleep, smd, smdexe, start, stop, surfaceflinger, svc, sync, system_server, tc, toolbox, top, touch, touchinput, uiautomator, umount, uptime, vdc, vmstat, vold, watchprops, wipe, wlandutservice, wpa_supplicant

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
cat infile > outfile
```

Or

```
dd if=infile of=outfile
```